How to use qiskit fake hardware
I need help with how to use qiskit Fake Hardware and which Fake Hardware can give results close to the actual solution of simulator. I am assuming, getting solution as close as possible to simulator means that its qubits are less noisy.  The qiskit version I am using is qiskit==1.0.0?

Your question is vague, so you need to add context. Why do you need to use a FakeBackend vs just a simulator? Do you need to model the backends' noise? Do you want to check connectivity limitations? Also, what do you mean by "give good results"? The best results will come from an ideal simulation. A FakeBackend will only give worse results. Or by "good" do you mean results that will resemble those of actual hardware? Please update your question to clarify what is it that you're trying to accomplish. You can start by checking qiskit's docs: https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/guides/local-testing-mode

Thank you for the response @diemilio.  I edited question. I need the least noisy fake hardware but I donot know which one is the least noisy.  The maximum requirement of my qubits is 14 qubits.

I think it is hard to extract that information. You could just pick a number of FakeBackends that meet your qubit criteria, run you sims in all of them and compare.

This code loops through those fake backends and finds the one that has the least average readout error.
import inspect
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import fake_provider

MIN_QUBITS = 14
#MIN_QUBITS = 100
MAX_ERROR = float('inf')
MIN_DEC_PlACE = 3

least_noisy_fakebackend = None
least_noisy_fakebackend_name = None
lowest_readout_error = MAX_ERROR

fb_list = [name for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(fake_provider) if inspect.isclass(obj) and name.startswith('Fake')]

def get_avg_readout_error(backend):
    try:
        nqubit = backend.configuration().n_qubits
        properties = backend.properties()
        tre = 0
        for qubit in range(nqubit):
            re = properties.qubit_property(qubit, 'readout_error')[0]
            tre += re
        return tre / nqubit
    except AttributeError:
        return MAX_ERROR

for backend_name in fb_list:
    try:
        backend_class = getattr(fake_provider, backend_name)
        backend = backend_class()

        # fake backend should have at least MIN_QUBITS qubits
        if backend.configuration().n_qubits < MIN_QUBITS:
            continue

        tmp = get_avg_readout_error(backend)
        #print(tmp)
        readout_error_str = f"{tmp:.10f}"
        # ignore backend that doesn't have enough precision
        if len(readout_error_str.split('.')[1].rstrip('0')) < MIN_DEC_PlACE:
            continue
        avg_readout_error = tmp 
        
        #if avg_readout_error != MAX_ERROR:  # Ignore backends without properties
            #print(f"{backend_name} average readout error: {avg_readout_error}")
    
        if avg_readout_error < lowest_readout_error:
            lowest_readout_error = avg_readout_error
            least_noisy_fakebackend_name = backend_name
            least_noisy_fakebackend = backend
    except:
        continue

if least_noisy_fakebackend_name:
    print(f"Least noisy backend: {least_noisy_fakebackend_name}, avg readout error: {lowest_readout_error}, n_qubits: {least_noisy_fakebackend.configuration().n_qubits}")
else:
    print("No FakeBackend matched")

The result looks like this with min 14 qubits:
Least noisy backend: FakeAuckland, avg readout error: 0.009055555555555553, n_qubits: 27


The issue is that average readout error might not be the limiting factor.
